# rails routing error crossdomain.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am able to run my application on my local machine. However, after I committed changes and deployed to a heroku hosted site I get the following error:

I have saved notes online that might be easier to read here:

http://shrib.com/f0fys8FT

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you migrated your database at Heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: thank you! I'm not sure why that worked but it did.